# couldnt create db schema "ACT_RU_IDENTITYLINK" in flowable engine

Tags: flowable

I have Spring Boot (2.3.4) app runs on Tomcat (9). When i try to build the project, flowable(6.6.0) engine gives this error. Schema is already created but it tries to create again. My problem is, i cannot deploy war code to the server because of it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded flowable-engine version 6.6.0 to 6.7.0, and its solved.